# RDP from one AWS ec2 to other and ping from one ec2 to other

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I have two ec2 windows 2019 instances. Both are in same private subnet subnet and same security group.
The security group allows all traffic for vpc cidr.

1. How to RDP from one private ec2(instance1) to another ec2 (instance2).
   When I try to rdp using privateip or private dns of instance1 to  instance2, it does not allow me to change the username, and username appears as HOSTNAME1/Administrator.
2. I am not able to ping one ec2 from other. however both are in same subnet and same security group and allows all traffic within VPC CIDR

Comment: Are you saying that the RDP connection is **successful**, but you are just unhappy with the Host name and User name?

Comment: `ping` uses ICMP, not TCP so you need to specifically add it to the Security Group rules. However, I would recommend against using `ping` to test connectivity because all it proves is whether `ping` works, which isn't actually what you are seeking. Instead, try to connect using the protocol and port you actual want to use.

Comment: Windows server disables ICMP by default afaik. Check the firewall settings on each Windows instance (and I mean the Windows firewall, not the AWS Security Group).